# How to implement the UDS protocol over xl-driver library for sending Diagnostics?

Tags: python, can-bus, diagnostics, automotive

i am trying to build UDS protocol over XL-driver library for building an diagnostic application, don't know from where is should start.

Comment: How well do you know UDS protocol is the counter question of mine.

Comment: i have a good knowledge about it , also trying to get ISO 14229-3 to be full understand that , i don't implemented it yet for sure .

Comment: What you really need is the ISO 15765-3 and ISO 15765-2. You need to know the TPConnection establishment, framing and buffering rules, half-duplex  full duplex TP connection specs etc. If you know them, implementing a UDS through XL lib is like writing a letter.

Comment: there is no 1765-3 2016 i think !! 
i have 1765-2 2016 , 1765-2 , 1765-3 2004 
am i right ?

Comment: The 15765 -3 2004  will be fine. Not much was changed during these years anyway.

Comment: sorry i don't make my question Clear , is 1765-2 2016 is enough ?

Comment: No, the 15765 -3 is more important for your usecase to know. 
15765 - 2 is not that important, and having the version 2016 is good, but still not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The whole stack of librairies exists in Python. Look at the [UdsOnCAN](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io) package that will handle the application layer. You can use it with [can-isotp](https://can-isotp.readthedocs.io) and [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for the underlying protocols. python-can support Vector hardware.

[This example](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/udsoncan/examples.html#using-uds-over-python-can) shows how to setup the three packages with a Vector interface.